# I am unable to initialise createOffer() after complete rendering of local stream?

Tags: react-native, webrtc, react-native-ios, webrtc-android, webrtc-ios

I am working on Video/Audio streaming functionality in my project and I am using **react-native-webrtc** library to implement the above features. Initially I am rendering local stream on **ComponentDidMount()**

```
componentDidMount () {
 this.getLocalStream();
}

getLocalStream() {
      mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(sourceInfos => {
      console.log("mediaDevices.enumerateDevices", sourceInfos);
      let videoSourceId;
      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if(sourceInfo.kind === "videoinput" && sourceInfo.facing === (this.state.isFront ? "front" : "environment")) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.id;
        }
      }
      mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ 
        audio: true, 
        // IF simulator/audio call is running for webrtc then video to false.
        video: this.state.isSwitching,
          facingMode: (this.state.isFront ? "user" : "environment"),
          optional: (videoSourceId ? [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] : [])
        }
      )
      .then(stream => { 
        InCallManager.start({media: 'audio'});
        InCallManager.startRingtone('_BUNDLE_');
        if (this.state.isSwitching === false) {
            InCallManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
            InCallManager.setForceSpeakerphoneOn(true); 
        }
        this.setState({videoUrl: stream.toURL(),})
        localStream = stream;
        pc.addStream(localStream);
        connectedUser = false;
        createPC(this.state.roomID,true);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Log error
        console.log('Error',error.message);
        this.setState({loading: false});
      });
      });
    }
```

After its successful rendering, I am initiating an offer() to another peer; however the method of RTCPeerConnection **pc.createOffer()** is not able to trigger and it is not executing the function, logic inside it. I tried many ways to make method trigger but it was unsuccessful.

```
const createPC = (socketId, isOffer) => {  

       pcPeers = {
         ...pcPeers,
         [socketId]: pc,
       };
      if (isOffer){
        pc.createOffer(function(desc) {
          log("fgf");
          console.log('createOffer', desc);
          pc.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {
            console.log('setLocalDescription', pc.localDescription);
            socket.emit('exchange', {'to': socketId, 'sdp': pc.localDescription });
          }, logError);
        }, logError);
      }


// On Add Stream:
 pc.onaddstream = event => {
  //console.log('onaddstream', event.stream);
  const remoteList = this.state.remoteList;
  remoteList[socketId] = event.stream.toURL();
  this.setState({
    remoteList: remoteList,
  });
};
// ice candidates
pc.onicecandidate = event => {
  log('Howeeeee');
  if (event.candidate) {
    socket.emit('exchange', { to: socketId, candidate: event.candidate });
  }
};
  return pc;
}
```

What was the cause of not getting fired even after providing all the parameters to the methods. As I am new to React Native, Can someone assist me where was I committing mistake. Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by downgrading react-native-webrtc version to 1.67.1 which is quite compatible with react native 0.59.0.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit]**

You make a mistake when you call createOffer().

createOffer() return Promise value, so it doesn't use parameter as a callback.

try like this

```
 if (isOffer){
    pc.createOffer()
        .then(function(desc) {
            console.log("createOffer, desc);
            pc.setLocalDescription(desc);
            // something to do
        }).
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

also I recommend read this [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer) about createOffer().

Comment: I have configured like this :
const configuration = {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]};

Comment: I even tried your solution, but not resolved, still it is not triggering the creatOffer() event!

Comment: Actually NO RTCPeerConnections are not getting fired! Even after using your code snippet, it doesn't seems to work!

Comment: My point is why the methods of RTCPeerConnections like createOffer(),onIceCandidates(), addStream() is not working in my case!? Does it have close connections with configuration!?  ex:  const configuration = {"iceServers": [stun.l.google.com:19302]};  const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration)?

Comment: Thanks man! I solved the issue by downgrading react-native-webrtc version to 1.67.1 which is quite compatible with react native 0.59.0